# Ellipse that acts like a button in JavaFX

Tags: java, button, javafx, ellipse

I have been trying to find a way to build two `Ellipse` object locationed next to each other that can be clicked and go to other screens by clicking one of them.

I don't know where to start. Right now I know only hope to build 2 regular buttons.

And how do we create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `Circle` as shape for the buttons. By default the shape will be scaled to the `Button` size, which results in ellipse shaped `Button`s.

```
Button btn = new Button("Say 'Hello World'");

// circular shape scaled to Button dimensions = ellipse
btn.setShape(new Circle(1));

// increase distance from edges to text
btn.setPadding(new Insets(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a label

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setId("button");
```

And then add a image ellipse or what ever that you want to your label.

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ellipse.png"));
label.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
```

Then add a mouse click event to the label

```
    label1.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
 @Override 
public void handle(MouseEvent e) { 
// write code to change screen
 } });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
elipse.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
    //Add scene change here.
});
```